# Fork in Join no Java

Tags: java, thread, paralelismo

Durante um projeto me sugeriram o uso de `Fork in Join` da API do Java ao invés de *threads*, não achei nada fácil de entender pelos exemplos achados no Google.

Eu entendi que é possível passar uma lista de tarefas e ele subdivide e depois reúne os resultados.

Gostaria de saber se é melhor que usar *threads* e se alguém tem um exemplo para mostrar ou até mesmo contar sua experiencia de uso com esse modelo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Fork/Join

A funcionalidade [`fork/join`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html), presente a partir do Java 7, pode ser um pouco difícil de entender a princípio, pois ela atende uma classe específica de problemas.

Segundo a documentação da classe [`ForkJoinTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#fork%28%29), a ideia é permitir um método mais eficiente de processamento paralelo impondo algumas restrições sobre o modo como as *threads* operam. O objetivo é conseguir dividir um problema em tarefas menores e executá-las independentemente, sem uso de sincronização (`synchronized`).

Se pensarmos um pouco, isso resolve muito bem questões de **[Programação Dinâmica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming)**. Um dos exemplos clássicos é o número de Fibonacci. O código a seguir é um exemplo de uso do `fork/join` que calcula o número de Fibonacci:

```java
public class Fibonacci extends RecursiveTask<Long> {

    long n;

    public Fibonacci(long n) {
        this.n = n;
    }

    @Override
    protected Long compute() {
        if (n <= 1) {
            return n;
        }
        Fibonacci f1 = new Fibonacci(n - 1);
        f1.fork();
        Fibonacci f2 = new Fibonacci(n - 2);
        return f2.compute() + f1.join();
    }

}
```

Podemos salientar os seguintes pontos:

- Estendemos [`RecursiveTask`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html), uma das duas implementações disponíveis de `ForkJoinTask`. Uma "tarefa recursiva" tem o propósito de executar subtarefas recursivas em paralelo e retornar um valor final.
- Dentro do método `compute()` ocorre a "mágica", onde definimos o limite da recursar no primeiro `if` e invocamos recursivamente instâncias da classe em novas threads.
- Ao invocar `f1.fork()`, estamos pedindo para que o cálculo de `f(n-2)` seja feito em outra *thread*. Isso libera o processamento paralelo de `f(n-1)`.
- Finalmente, invocamos `f2.compute()` para calcular o valor imediatamente e `f1.join()` para recuperar o valor do `fork` ou aguardar que o processamento termine.

Você pode executar o código acima da seguinte forma:

```java
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(4);
Fibonacci fibonacci = new Fibonacci(10);
long resultado = pool.invoke(fibonacci);
System.out.println(resultado);
```

A class [`ForkJoinPool`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) permite o gerenciamento das tarefas paralelas e o parâmetro do construtor estabelece o nível de paralelismo, isto é, quantas *threads* serão usadas simultaneamente.

O método `pool.invoke(fibonacci)` inicia o processamento, aguarda o cálculo e retorna o número calculado.

---

## ThreadPoolExecutor

Porém, se o seu problema não entra na categoria de problema onde "dividir para conquistar" recursivamente é a melhor estratégia, você pode usar APIs mais genéricas, tal como  [`ThreadPoolExecutor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html).

Ela faz parte do mesmo pacote que `fork/join`, pois ambas implementam [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html), mas sem a natureza recursiva e limitada da "irmã".

Para criar uma instência de `ThreadPoolexecutor`:

```java
ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
        4, //tamanho inicial do pool
        8, //tamanho máximo do pool  
        10000, //tempo de espera máximo para cada thread na fila 
        TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, //unidade de tempo
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>() //implementação da fila de theads
);
```

Depois, pedimos para executar threads e usamos *futures* para guardar a promessa de um resultado futuro:

```java
Future<Integer> f1 = threadPoolExecutor.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return 1;
    }
});

Future<Integer> f2 = threadPoolExecutor.submit(new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() throws Exception {
        return 2;
    }
});
```

Nota que o código acima usa o método `submit()` para solicitar a execução de dois `Callable`s. Um `Callable` representa uma *thread*, assim como um `Runnable`, mas retornando um valor.

A classe `Future` guarda uma referência para a *thread* de forma que podemos continuar a execução e recuperar o resultado quando estiver pronto, assim:

```java
try {
    Integer r1 = f1.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    Integer r2 = f2.get(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    System.out.println(r1 + r2);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

No exemplo acima, usei o método `get()` das instâncias de `Future` para aguardar o processamento e recuperar efetivamente o resultado.

Os parâmetros indicam que o tempo limite de espera é de mil milissegundos. Se passar disso, um `TimeoutException` será lançado.

---

## Considerações finais

A escolha entre usar *threads* clássicas, `fork/join`, `ThreadPoolExecutor` ou qualquer outro mecanismo depende da natureza do problema que você tenta resolver. Uma abordagem não é necessariamente melhor que as outras para todos os tipos de problemas.

Além disso, determinadas situações exigirão implementações mais específicas, onde você vai precisar estender as classes e interfaces da API `java.util.concurrent`. A boa notícia é que essa API é feita com isso em mente.

Comment: Pois é, meu problema na verdade já implementei `threads` para manipular e-mail da API `JavaMail`, pois eu realizo procedimento de separar mensagens por remetente, separar mensagens por conteúdo, criar pastas. Coisas deste tipo, mas pretendo usar concorrência para outras funcionalidades no sistema.

Comment: @Macario1983 Corrigido!

Comment: eu usei um código com `forkInJoin`, cara muito show de bola, problema é como você colocou, ele não permite sincronização, algo que tive que alterar em meu código pois eu atribuía a um vetor quais mensagens não tem anexo. Então optei por passar um `list` para facilitar. Vou postar o código também para caso alguém queira ver, ou alguém possa corrigir.

Answer (score 2):

Existe um projeto chamado [Java Concurrent Animated](http://javaconcurrenta.sourceforge.net/) que criou uma aplicação de demonstração das capacidades de Java em programação concorrente / paralela.

Você pode baixar um demo (com os fontes) que você pode usar para estudar tudo relacionado à esse tema.

Existem vários tipos de animações que demonstram como usar cada modelo de programação concorrente. Durante a animação, trechos do código de exemplo vão sendo destacados, dando uma boa ideia de como implementar.

O demo é apenas um JAR autoexecutável. É só dar duplo clique.

É muito legal e muito bem feito!

Comment: Muito boa sua recomendação!

Answer (score 0):

Estou postando o código como exemplo para quem quiser ver como foi feito. Este pode ser alterado por quem quiser, desde que tenha melhorado.

```
package service.forkinjoin;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.RecursiveAction;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;

import service.FileUtil;

public class ForkSortMessages extends RecursiveAction {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1092415796824205832L;
    private List<Message> listMessages;
    private List<Message> listMessagesToDelete;

    public ForkSortMessages(List<Message> listMessages, List<Message> listMessagesToDelete) {
        this.listMessages = listMessages;
        this.listMessagesToDelete = listMessagesToDelete;
    }

    @Override
    protected void compute() {

        List<RecursiveAction> actions = new ArrayList<>();

        if (this.listMessages.size() <= Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()) {
            try {
                this.separateMessages();
            } catch (MessagingException | IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {

            int end = this.listMessages.size() / 2;
            actions.add(new ForkSortMessages(this.listMessages.subList(0, end), this.listMessagesToDelete));
            end += this.listMessages.size() % 2 == 0 ? 0 : 1;
            actions.add(new ForkSortMessages(this.listMessages.subList(end, this.listMessages.size()), this.listMessagesToDelete));
            invokeAll(actions);
        }
    }

    private void separateMessages() throws MessagingException, IOException {

        for (Message message : this.listMessages) {

            if ((this.hasNoAttachment(message.getContentType()) || (this.hasNoXmlAttachment(message)))) {
                listMessagesToDelete.add(message);
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean hasNoAttachment(String content) {
        return !content.contains("multipart/MIXED");
    }

    private boolean hasNoXmlAttachment(Message message) throws IOException, MessagingException {

        Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();

        for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {

            MimeBodyPart mimeBodyPart = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(i);

            if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(mimeBodyPart.getDisposition())) {

                if (FileUtil.isXmlFile(mimeBodyPart.getFileName())) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Esta é uma resposta como ficou em definitivo ou faz parte da sua pergunta?

Comment: @bigown foi um código que fiz, não sei esta 100% como é a ideia, mas fiz baseado no que vi em alguns exemplos. Estou deixando para que possa ajudar.